# What is wrong with my second conditional?

Tags: javascript

I am fairly new to javascript and I ran into a logical error in my code.

```
var btn = document.querySelector("button");
var para = document.querySelector(".paragraph");
var prevVal = document.querySelector(".prevVal");

var randomArray = [" Hello", " Hi", " How are you?", " How was your day?", " Tell me a joke.", " I am having a good day."];
var previousValueArray = [];

btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  var randomValue = randomArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomArray.length)];

  //pushing value in previousValueArray
  previousValueArray.push(randomValue);
  if (previousValueArray.length === 6){
     previousValueArray.shift();
  }
  if (previousValueArray[previousValueArray.length - 1] === randomValue){
     para.textContent = "Sorry, but this was the previous value. Click again please.";
  }

  para.textContent = randomValue;
  prevVal.textContent = previousValueArray;
});
```

I am trying to get my second `if` conditional to change the `textConent` of `para` . I am testing to see if the last value in `previousValueArray` and `randomValue` are equal. To make this a little more clear, I am trying to create a test project that if the user clicks a button, it outputs a random value from `randomArray` - I got this working. Next, I wanted to go to the next level and make sure my program didn't execute the same value twice in a row. I can't get this to work. Any help?

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  <button type="button">Random Value</button>
  <p class="paragraph"></p>
  <p class="prevVal"></p>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add html code as well for testing

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? It's not clear!

Comment: What is the question? What research have you made?

Comment: @PankajShukla My second `if` statement doesn't work. It's a logical error. I want it to print "Sorry, but this was the previous value. Click again please." if the last value of `previousValueArray` is equal to `randomValue`.

Comment: @Bustedspoke are you for something like this - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/BRmPmv

Comment: add another condition to check the random value with prev value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your condition is always true, since you push the new value to the Array (= last element) and then compare it with itself. Then, `para` gets overwritten with `randomValue` anyway. This works (except quick fix with `-2`:

```
var btn = document.querySelector("button");
var para = document.querySelector(".paragraph");
var prevVal = document.querySelector(".prevVal");

var randomArray = [" Hello", " Hi", " How are you?", " How was your day?", " Tell me a joke.", " I am having a good day."];
var previousValueArray = [];

btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  var randomValue = randomArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomArray.length)];

  //pushing value in previousValueArray
  previousValueArray.push(randomValue);
  if (previousValueArray.length === 6){
     previousValueArray.shift();
  }

  // randomValue just pushed to the array -> last element.
  // comparison with itself is always true, so use the element before that:
  // (may fail at beginning with empty Array)
  if (previousValueArray[previousValueArray.length - 2] === randomValue){
     para.textContent = "Sorry, but this was the previous value. Click again please.";
  }
  else{
    // don't overwrite
    para.textContent = randomValue;
  }

prevVal.textContent = previousValueArray;

});
```

Comment: Thanks! This also worked. I'll keep this in mind for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

You could move the randomly selected text to the end of the array. Then the next time you will only look at one element less for picking a random text.

Here is how to do that with `splice`:

```js
var btn = document.querySelector("button");
var para = document.querySelector(".paragraph");
var prevVal = document.querySelector(".prevVal");

var randomArray = [" Hello", " Hi", " How are you?", " How was your day?", 
                   " Tell me a joke.", " I am having a good day."];
var valueCount = randomArray.length;

btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * valueCount);
  var randomValue = randomArray[i];

  para.textContent = randomValue;
  prevVal.textContent = randomArray[valueCount] || '';
    
  // move selected value to the end
  randomArray.push(randomArray.splice(i, 1));
  // Next time this value cannot be selected
  valueCount = randomArray.length - 1;
});
```

```html
<button type="button">Random Value</button>
<p class="paragraph"></p>
<p class="prevVal"></p>
```

NB: Your code had two issues: you tested for equality too late, since you had already pushed onto the array (so the condition is always true), and the duplicate warning message was never visible since it was overwritten in the next statement.

Comment: Thank you. This worked. This was a better solution than what I was initially trying to do.

Comment: This may work but it is not an answer to the question ;-)

Comment: Where are we saying `"Sorry, but this was the previous value. Click again please."`?Is that not needed in this solution?

Comment: Better prevent than fix ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit broad. I will assume you want to get a unique random element from the array?

Do it like this:

**1.** Define an array of all available elements:

```
var array = ["Hi", "Hello", "Hey", "Whatever"];
```

Notice I don't leave any trailing spaces at the start of the word. If you want padding, use CSS.

**2.** Make a function that would roll a value, and then remove it from array:

```
function roll(a){
    if(a.length > 0){
        var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * a.length);
        var e = a[i];
        a.splice(i, 1);
        return e;
    }
    else return false;
}
```

**3.** Attach the listener as usual:

```
var array = ["Hi..", "..."];
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    var text = roll(array);
    if(!text){
        // ran out of unique values
    }
    else paragraph.innerHTML = text;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if (previousValueArray[previousValueArray.length - 1] == randomValue){
```

PreviousValueArray and randomValue will not result in === ( true ) because one is array and the other is number but you have to use == for validation in this case.

Comment: Both are strings - in fact, they are (always) identical.

Comment: `"test" == "test"; "test" === "test"; var s = "test"; var a = [];  a.push(s);  a[a.length-1] == s;  a[a.length-1] === s;`